# How can I refer to data.frame columns in lapply?

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

I want to write a function and use `lapply` to automatically run some models with different covariates. But I cannot change the variables that I need to use for each model.

```
bootstrap_vars <- list(vars1=c(1,2,3), vars2=c(2,3,4), vars3=c(1,3,4))

full_mod <- lm(Y ~ X[,full_vars])
getFstat <- function(Vars, X, Y, full_mod) {
   boot_mod <- lm(Y ~ X[,Vars], data=data)
   ano <- anova(full_mod, boot_mod, test="F")
   # cat("Variables:", Vars, ". F-stat: ", ano$F[2], "\n")
   ano$F[2] # Return F-statistic between full model and one bootstrap model
}
all_F <- unlist(lapply(bootstrap_vars, FUN = getFstat, X=X, Y=Y, full_mod=full_mod))
```

It cannot recognize the X in the `lapply` and show `anova` has different dataset for boot_mod and full_mod? How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

`lapply` we select each element of the list in turn such as `list[[1]]`, `list[[2]]`, etc... In your case, you can slightly change the structure of your function to make it work (although I couldn't test it because your example is not reproducible):

```
bootstrap_vars <- list(vars1=c(1,2,3), vars2=c(2,3,4), vars3=c(1,3,4))

full_mod <- lm(Y ~ X[,full_vars])

## Function that will intake the variable Vars for list[[Vars]]
getFstat <- function(Vars, Y, full_mod) {
   boot_mod <- lm(Y ~ Vars, data=data)
   ano <- anova(full_mod, boot_mod, test="F")
   # cat("Variables:", Vars, ". F-stat: ", ano$F[2], "\n")
   ano$F[2] # Return F-statistic between full model and one bootstrap model
}
all_F <- unlist(lapply(bootstrap_vars, FUN = getFstat, Y=Y, full_mod=full_mod))
```

In this case, your function will basically run:

```
getFstat(bootstrap_vars[[1]], ...)
getFstat(bootstrap_vars[[2]], ...)
getFstat(bootstrap_vars[[3]], ...)
```